# Sorting and creating map using lambda in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a  list like

```
List<Event>
```

where Event has properties like eventId, eventName, groupId etc. There can be multiple events belonging to same group. I want a map like

```
Map<Long, Event>
```

where key is the groupId and Event is the one which has max eventId. So, basically I just want to sort list of events belonging to same group and then find out the one which has maximum event Id which can be used as a value. I am not sure how this can be achieved. Please assist.

I would like to achieve this using lambda in single line code.

Comment: `I would like to achieve this using lambda in single line code.` Why?

Comment: why do you need to group the `Event` based on `groupId` when all you want as an end result is an `Event` that has the highest `evenId`? if so just query the `List<Event>` if not then please elaborate...

Comment: or do you want the Maximum `Event` of each group?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
Map<Long, Event> result = events.stream().collect( 
Collectors.toMap( (e) -> e.getGroupid() , (e) -> e, 
(e1, e2) -> e1.getEventId().compareTo( e2.getEventId() ) > 0 ? e1 : e2 ) );
```

Comment: Think you mean `> 0`

Comment: Or replace `(e1, e2) -> e1.getEventId().compareTo( e2.getEventId() ) > 0 ? e1 : e2 )` with `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingLong(Event::getEventId))` (looks better with static imports…